# ¿Cuando trato de imprimir un datatable mediante un ajax y con la funcion .html me sale el error internal server?

Tags: ajax, datatables, servidor

Bueno mi problema radica en que al intentar imprimir en el tbody de mi datatble la información en tipo cadena que obtengo de mi consulta de sql server me marca el error internal server, pero no siempre, solo cuando la cadena de texto es muy larga, por ejemplo si son 50 registros no hay problema y me hace la impresión correcta pero si ya son 30 o 400, en adelante me sale el error internal server error.

codigo aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getInforRecords(int idUpload,int tipoFile)
{
    UploadGEOController geocont = new UploadGEOController();
    List<UploadGEO> listgeo = new List<UploadGEO>();
    string htmlreturn = "";

    listgeo = geocont.RecordsExcel(idUpload,tipoFile);

    foreach (UploadGEO elemento in listgeo) {
        htmlreturn += "<tr><td>" + elemento.AreaFuncional + "</td><td>" + elemento.DominioFuncional + "</td><td>" + elemento.Periodo + "</td><td>" + elemento.Proveedor + "</td>" +
        "<td> <div class='col-lg-12 text-center'><i id='ModalRecords' class='fa fa-eye' title='Aqui Usted podra ver detalles'  aria-hidden='true' style='cursor:pointer;'></i></div>" +
        "" +
        "</td></tr>";
    }


    return htmlreturn;

}
```

Codigo .js

```
function getRecords(idExcel,tipoFile) {
    $("#IdRecords").removeClass("hidden");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AdminView.aspx/getInforRecords",
        data: '{idUpload:"' + idExcel + '",tipoFile:"' + tipoFile + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //console.log(result.d);
            $("#tbodyRecord").html(result.d);
            //Genera el formato de datatable a la tabla
            tableRecord = $('#tableRecords').DataTable({
                language: {
                    url: 'Json/SpanishDataTable.json'
                }
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error,status,xhr)
        }
    });
}
```

Realmente no se a que se deba el problema, no se si haya algún tipo de limite o algo por el estilo al momento de retornar cadena.

Comment: Supongo que lo tienes publicado en un servidor de IIS con windows server o algo así?

Comment: Si esta en un IIS de otra computadora.. tendrias que entrar a ese server y abrir el proyecto desde alli en localhost, con esto podras ver el detalle del error o de la excepcion, tambien podrias poner un logger como log4net y guardar los erroes en un archivo de texto, despues verlo para saber exactamente cual es el error.

Comment: A veces aunque se configure el limite en el web.config, se debe configurar en el servidor donde esta alojada la aplicacion.  Te paso la liga mas o menos de como se hace: http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm